# Can we say characteristic polynomial of the matrix $A+B$ is same as sum of characteristic polynomials of $A$ and $B$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose that $\psi_A(x)$ denotes the characteristic polynomial of the square matrix $A$. What relation can we draw between $\psi_{A+B}(x)$ and $\psi_A(x)$ and $\psi_B(x)$ ?

Let me show what was my approach.

First I choose $A, B$ as square matrix of order 2. Then after computation, I figure out that $$\psi_{A+B}(2x)=2[\psi_A(x)+\psi_B(x)]$$

But the problem is for $A\in M_3$ I am unable to determine or derive any suitable result. I mean there should be some standard process in the determinant but because of lack of that knowledge I am unable to proceed.

Please help me determine the general relation. Thanks in advance

Comment: I think the title of this question was not completely correct, but if anyone finds any suitable title, my request, please edit

Comment: As far as I know there is no general relationship between the characteristic polynomials of two matrices and the characteristic polynomial of the sum of those matrices.  Any relationship you're currently witnessing is probably a coincidence of the particular matrices you're looking at.

Comment: The characteristic polynomial is always monic, so they certainly can't be added.

Answer (score 2):

If $A=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$ and $B=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$, then $\chi_A(s) = \chi_B(s) = s(s-1)$, but
$\chi_{A+B}(s) = (s-1)^2$.